# How to email CLLocationCoordinate2D as a link

Tags: iphone, email, location

I am trying to emulate the Maps 'Share Location' via email functionality.

I have the latitude and longitude of my location and am currently using it to display the location on a map via MKMapView.

I also have functionality that composes an email from the app and I would like to include the location in it but can not figure out how to construct a link, using the longitude and latitude.

I have seen other apps with apps with this functionality so I know it is possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

The link should open Google Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where should it link to? Your app or Google Maps? For the latter, check out the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1). For the former, you have to construct your own URL scheme and then create a string that matches your scheme.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I couldn't not find the documentation anywhere. Thanks.